# How can I call an async method within a sync method?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

I'm trying to call an async task (SIn) within a synch method (SignIn). I need the synch method because I'm passing ref to that method. But when I'm calling the async task, the GUI is frozen. The async task is a simple login with the onedrive sdk.

I've tried to waited the task, but the GUI still frozen. I've also tried creating a new Thread, but it didn't work too. How can I call the async method?

```
public override bool SignIn(ref User user)
{
   try
   {
      signInEnd = false;
      signinUser = user;

      Task<bool> task = SIn();
      task.Wait();

      return task.Result;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      return false;
   }
}

public async Task<bool> SIn()
{
   var msaAuthProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(
          this.oneDriveClientId,
          this.oneDriveReturnUrl,
          this.scopes,
          new CredentialVault(this.oneDriveClientId));
   await msaAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
   driveClient = new OneDriveClient(this.oneDriveBaseUrl, msaAuthProvider);
}
```

Comment: There are no good / recommended ways to call an async path from a sync path; you'd be forced to use sync-over-async to wait for it to complete, and *that's a bad thing*; the only *correct* solution here is to make `[Value]Task<bool> SignInAsync` - although you might need to change the API to lose the `ref`

Comment: Why do you need ref? You are not assigning anything to the user argument.

Comment: A good read about this matter https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Wait()` blocks the UI thread which means that the continuation of `SIn()`, i.e. the part that will eventually be executed once the `Task` returned by `AuthenticateUserAsync()` has completed, won't be able to execute on this thread. This results in a deadlock.

You may be able to get around this by avoiding capturing the context by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `SIn()`:

```
public async Task<bool> SIn()
{
    var msaAuthProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(
           this.oneDriveClientId,
           this.oneDriveReturnUrl,
           this.scopes,
           new CredentialVault(this.oneDriveClientId));
    await msaAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    driveClient = new OneDriveClient(this.oneDriveBaseUrl, msaAuthProvider);
}
```

But the "real" solution to this kind of issues is not to mix asynchronous and synchronous code, i.e. `SignIn` should be asynchronous and await `SIn()`. Don't block on asynchronous code by calling `Wait()` or `Result`:

```
public Task<bool> SignIn(User user)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        return await SIn();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please refer to @Stephen Cleary's [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

mm8 is right that not calling async from inside a sync method is the best way to solve your issue,

remember that the `public async void EventHandler()` method was specifically designed for running long running tasks from a gui linked control

However it isn't always possible to rewrite an entire system to be async when only one small section needs changing

In this case you should avoid waiting for the results as this makes the async process pointless, what you can do though is break your synchronous code into 2 parts a before and after

- the before method will prep and launch the task,
- the after handles the results

ie

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int delay)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    return "complete";
}

public void StartGettingData()
{
    GetData(5000).ContinueWith(t => CompleteGetData(t.Result), TaskScheduler.Current);
}

public void CompleteGetData(string message)
{
    UpdateStatus(message);
}
```

this method does have the added complexity of requiring you to ensure thread safety yourself, which is why the async/await functionality was introduced